# Set AppID/AppSecret for Facebook Authentication after starting in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

My ASP.NET Core MVC application has a configuration page where the user will set connection strings and other configuration items for the webapp. I wanted to include setting the AppId/AppSecret for Facebook and Google authentication here as well.

So the first-time startup of the webapp will have no AppId/AppSecret and when the user completes the first run configuration, the AppId/AppSecret will be saved to the database. Then configure the FacebooOptions/GoogleOptions so that we can redirect to the signin page afterward.

Is there a way to access and modify the FacebookOptions/GoogleOptions from within a controller?

Right now we are using `appsettings.json` and initializing via:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/signin");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/access-denied");
        })
        .AddFacebook(options => {
            // Instead of setting these values here, 
            // we'd like to set the AppId/AppSecret from a configuration page
            
            options.AppId = "xxx";
            options.AppSecret = "xxx";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
        })
        .AddGoogle(options => {
            // Instead of setting these values here, 
            // we'd like to set the AppId/AppSecret from a configuration page
            
            options.ClientId = "yyy";
            options.ClientSecret = "yyy";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
        });
```

The webapp is written in C#, ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Comment: Did you created the facebook `appId` and `secrect` accordingly? Please have a look on our [official guideline here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-facebook-authentication)

Comment: The problem i'm having is that it is a timing issue, when we first install the aspnetcore mvc app to IIS, appid/appsecret are all empty strings... 

the code will detect that the systme is newly installed and redirects the user to the /configuration page. From there, the user will enter the facebook/google appid and appsecret.

unfortunately, aspnetcore has already completed the startup phase and there the external login is already configured with empty appid/appsecret. so in order to to get those credentials set properly, we need the user to restart iis/server

Comment: my question is how can we configure the appid/appsecret after the startup phase

Comment: I was looking for a way to get access to the AddFacebook() and AddGoogle() objects thru DI on the controller level but i just couldn't get the object injected into the ctor of the controller

Comment: Using `custom middleware` we can do that, you can have a [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0)